# How to classify one specific word in sentence?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, nlp, deep-learning

How to classify one specific word in the sentence?

For example, I have:

> "Thus, SENP2 may be a promising therapeutic target for BC"

and

> "The JNK Signaling Pathway in Renal Fibrosis"

In the first sentence "SENP2" is a gene, and in second sentence "JNK" isn't a gene but is on the list of genes.

I want to train a neural network (I think CNN + RNN) which will only classify is one word per sentence. At the input, I have Embedding layer with pre-trained word2vec from PubMed. I also have the positions of these words in sentences in the CSV file, as another column for a particular sentence. Can I train my network normally, that is, whole sentences and label them as 0 and 1? How to predict in new sentences using pre-trained model?

Comment: So you want to train a classifier that, given a sentence, decides whether it contains a gene? Also, have you tried a simpler model than NN first? If the problem turns out to actually be easy then it makes no sense to use NNs.

Comment: Yes, I want to train a classifier that, given a sentence, decides whether it contains a gene. Yes, I also tried SVM, but I want to train an NN classifier.
I want to train on 500k positive and 500k negative dataset. Then, I want to predict on 40 million other sentences, where is a gene or not.

Comment: Okay then, just one more question: What have you tried and why didn't it work? The question is not clear, are you asking how to use keras?

Comment: I tried to train on all sentences (500k contains gene and 500k does not contain gene) using word2vec on the input layer. Then I tried to predict on a pre-trained model with another sentence. It works good, but on the sentences. I want to point specifically to the word in the sentence and whether this word is a gene.

Comment: @Oskar You'll have to build a new dataset for that, as far as I am aware. Once you have a dataset that contains not only the sentences, but also the status of whether or not each word in the sentence is a gene the training should be trivial.

Comment: @Omegastick No, I put into neural network only sentences (such as in the example), without the position of the gene. Positions of genes I have in another CSV column. Can I somehow use it?

Comment: Yeah, if you've got the position of the gene then you can do that super easy. When you get the output from the network during training, you just add an extra dimension for the location of the gene in the sentence. I would actually recommend adding in a few dimensions and using one-hot encoding if you are using fixed-size inputs.

Comment: @Omegastick Thanks! Check your e-mail from GitHub, I send you a simple picture of my dataset and Keras architecture.

Comment: @Omegastick You can answer my question via e-mail? Best

Comment: @Oskar I'm at work at the moment, I'll try and check when I get back.

Comment: @Omegastick Thanks! :) I can send you a full code of my pre-processing and architecture in second e-mail.